# Displaying reCaptcha from html-unit in GUI

Tags: recaptcha, http-unit

I am currently working on a account creator for various websites (Java code can be viewed here: https://github.com/xushWT/M2AccountCreator)

No I am running into a problem where I need to let the user solve google recaptchas manually, which has worked great for other captchas that are just image based, reference here: https://github.com/xushWT/M2AccountCreator/blob/master/src/lidev/InternationalAccCreator.java#L22-L33

Is anyone experienced in displaying a recaptcha from a headless browser to a GUI so the user himself can solve it?

I hope you could understand what I mean, thanks in advance.